# how to make SRC Tag detect link source

Tags: javascript, html

is this possible for src tag, img/audio/html
currently im using this.

```
<span>Source</span> : <span>soundcloud.com</span>
<audio src="soundcloud.com/example"> </audio>
```

Comment: Say what now???

Comment: Can you rephrase the question in a more detailed way?

Answer (score 0):

Your src attribute not detecting link source? here's a quick fix

if you are dealing with an external link(link to another website)
add "https://www.soundcloud.com/example" to your src attribute

like this
Source : soundcloud.com
 
(This is because sometimes your browser may not understand if the link is to an external site or to a folder on your computer that is named after the site)